# Google Appengine Datastore - python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a problem with google appengine, I am unable to initialize any tables using python's `put()` command

here is my code:

```
    import webapp2
    import datetime
    from google.appengine.ext import db
    from google.appengine.api import users

    class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.write('Hello world!')

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainHandler)
    ], debug=True)




    class Employee(db.Model):
      name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
      role = db.StringProperty(required=True,
                               choices=set(["executive", "manager", "producer"]))
      hire_date = db.DateProperty()
      new_hire_training_completed = db.BooleanProperty(indexed=False)
      email = db.StringProperty()


    e = Employee(name="John",
                 role="manager",
                 email="joe@joe.com")
    e.hire_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    e.put()
```

and the error is as the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\python27_x64\blog\blog\main.py", line 46, in <module>
        e.put()
      File "C:\python27_x64\lib\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1069, in put
        self._populate_internal_entity()
      File "C:\python27_x64\lib\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1038, in _populate_internal_entity
        self._entity = self._populate_entity(_entity_class=_entity_class)
      File "C:\python27_x64\lib\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1107, in _populate_entity
        entity = _entity_class(self.kind(), **kwds)
      File "C:\python27_x64\lib\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 759, in __init__
        _app = datastore_types.ResolveAppId(_app)
      File "C:\python27_x64\lib\google\appengine\api\datastore_types.py", line 228, in ResolveAppId
        ValidateString(app, 'app', datastore_errors.BadArgumentError)
      File "C:\python27_x64\lib\google\appengine\api\datastore_types.py", line 176, in ValidateString
        raise exception('%s must not be empty.' % name)
    BadArgumentError: app must not be empty.
```

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: What does your app.yaml look like?

Comment: Are you running your code through dev_appserver, or directly with python?

Comment: i am running directly with python and using paste to initialize an http server. APP.YAML IS : application: udacity-cs253
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: blog.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"

Comment: You should use dev_appserver: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld

Comment: I know I am being pedantic, but there are no "tables" in the datastore.  You are unable to initialiase a model and this is purely you code level and not an enforcement at the datastore level.  And  are you absolutely certain the code above is pasted from your code and not the example docs.  And lastly if you are just starting out with appengine and the datastore, then I strongly suggest you stop using db right now, and work the the ndb tutorials.  ndb is a better api for pretty much all applications.

Answer (score 0):

The error raise at Line 46 of main.py, so I assume you copied a snippet of your code.

Move the following lines into MainHandler class and you should be able to create an Entity call Employee in datastore:

```
e = Employee(name="John",
             role="manager",
             email="joe@joe.com")
e.hire_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
e.put()
```